# Gulp server doesn't work

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-connect

I'm using Gulp and I've installed `gulp-livereload` and `gulp-connect` to set up a development server. Here's my `gulpfile.js`:

```
"use strict";
const gulp = require('gulp');
const livereload = require('gulp-livereload');
const connect = require('gulp-connect');

gulp.task('connect', () => {
  connect.server({
    root: 'app',
    livereload: true
  });
});
```

When I run `gulp connect` in my shell, the server does start on `localhost:8080`, but when I try to navigate to it, it returns me a 404 error. I'm working on Win10 and use Microsoft Edge. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Can you show us what is in the app directory (is there an index.html file)  ?

Comment: please, post that as an answer, that WAS the problem -- I didn't make an `app` directory with `index.html`. my bad :(

Comment: @Nix thanks! I can accept it in 8 minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with that gulp file with the assumption that you have an index.html file at `app/index.html`